# How to get cloth + wind simulation in 2.80?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I tried the regular flow of:

- Creating a plane
- Scaling to ~0.5mX0.5m, applying scaling
- Subdividing by 10 cuts
- Creating a vertex group out of one of the edges for pinning
- Apply cloth simulation, use group as pin, preset set to "silk"

So far so good - the cloth hangs from the pinned group. Next I try to add wind by adding force field, set type to wind and shape to plane.

First, nothing really happens and my cloth doesn't seem to be affected by the wind at all. Second, unlike the tutorials I've seen, trying to rotate the force field direction rotates the cloth as well, which to my understanding shouldn't be happening.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

.blend link [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8kcfsqnjxm5jmes/wind_example.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out. The field should be added through `Add`->`Force Field`->`Wind` and not through the physics pane of the cloth itself. That enables rotation. When I do that and set the strength to something like 5000 it works as expected.